# Cannot rsync to secondary HDD on remote server; boot drive works fine

Tags: server, backup, rsync, file-sharing, mediaserver

I am currently in the process of setting my girlfriend's desktop up as a home file server/media center. I personally use rsync to do large incremental file backups, and am trying to get it to work so she can back up her Mac laptop's local iTunes folder to the remote desktop.

On the server, which is running Ubuntu 16.04 (actually a desktop), there is a 240GB SSD as a boot drive and a 500GB HDD as a secondary storage device. Naturally, it would be preferable to rsync to the hard drive, especially considering the size of the music library (~200GB).

Strangely, I am able to rsync from the local machine to any folder on the SSD, but when I try to rsync to the hard drive, I get an error. Specifically, this command works great:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh /Volumes/500GB\ WD\ HDD/iTunes/ user@192.168.1.108:/home/user/Music/iTunes/
```

But as soon as I try this:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh /Volumes/500GB\ WD\ HDD/iTunes/ user@192.168.1.108:/media/user/500GB\ Drive/iTunes/
```

I get the following error:

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-51/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. This is truly stumping me.

P.S. I am sure that the path to the HDD on the remote folder is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using sudo when executing the above commands. If you use sudo while using SSH/SCP it will try and log you in as root at the destination (desktop).

Make sure the user you are logging in as over ssh has permission to write in the directory you have the drive mounted as. While you are on the desktop try and open the folders from the file manager, try and copy a file to it by dragging and dropping. Do not enter the sudo password at any time.

If you can't do the above while on the system and logged in as the user that is being used for SSH then you won't be able to do so over SSH either.

Try mounting the hard rive inside of the `/home/*username*/` folder on the server. This way you are sure you can write to it with SCP/SSH.